# Custom update process for ubuntu

Tags: apt, java, ppa

I a have remote embedded system with Ubuntu on it. Also it runs our proprietary Java application Jar on it. In order to update that jar I have tried to set up private PPA repository, but it seems too complicated for me as a beginner. is there some simpler solution to automate such actions. I just need to have automatic jar update with script execution afterwards to systems behind NAT.

P.S. I have publicly accessible server.

P.S. Software is made by us and run only within the companies devices.

Comment: have you tried updating using sudo apt-get update? check this http://blog.bluedrive.ro/?p=28

Comment: I have failed setting apt repository up. So the question is "alternatives or some simplifications please".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use git-fs for updates like some other OSes has. automatic, safe, ...
[some reference for starting](http://tech.slashdot.org/story/12/10/09/163210/os-upgrades-powered-by-git)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the luls:
I have found some solid solution called OSGi and one of the popular implementations : [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/)

But I think sdfsdfsdf's answer would work better for my circumstances.